# Is there a way to connect nodejs to a local Google Datastore

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

With Java and Python GAE applications can connect to local Datastore in development mode before send to appspot.com

I have install a Datastore as Local Development Server
https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver

I want to connect to local datastore using nodejs, I read this Google Tutorial to use Datastore with nodejs, but I don't found any information about how to connect

I follow this tutorial, but this only connect to a appstpot Datastore.
https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_nodejs/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. The Cloud Datastore nodejs implementation uses JSON, which the local development server doesn't support yet. See the note at the top of this page: https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver

Answer (score 3):

Now you can with gcloud, read the documents at:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node

Answer (score 2):

You can use [datastore-emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator) in your local apps.

Firstly, install google-cloud library. Then run,

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud -q components install beta cloud-datastore-emulator
gcloud -q beta emulators datastore start --no-store-on-disk --project='your_project_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

When I use `gcloud.datastore.dataset({projectId: 'project-id'])` I'm getting the following error:

> gcloud.datastore.dataset is not a function.

It works only when I set `var ds = cloud.datastore({projectId: 'project-id'])`.